# Bringing in value of Coupon Code into "tax" calculation.php in magento

Tags: magento

Im trying to pull in the name of the discount code currently applied to the cart into the calculation.php file. The name of the discount code is optionalTax but Im having trouble passing it through or retrieving it directly. Its appears to be referenced as `$quote->getCouponCode()` in mage/sales/model/quote.php and I want to use it in 
mage/tax/model/calculation.php

Anyone have any idea on how to call it in as I've tried using the model as per (which I think is correct)

```
public function calcTaxAmount($price, $taxRate, $priceIncludeTax=false, $round=true)
    {
        $taxRate = $taxRate/100;

        if ($priceIncludeTax) {
            $amount = $price*(1-1/(1+$taxRate));
        } else {
   $cModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/sales');
   $thisDiscountCode = $cModel->$quote->getCouponCode();
   die($thisDiscountCode);
   $amount = $price*$taxRate; 
        }

        if ($round) {
            return $this->round($amount);
        } else {
            return $amount;
        }
    }
```

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the quote from right model i guess:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
```

Comment: Thanks Anton, that set me well on my way in the end.

Comment: if this solved your issue then you should accept this as a correct answer

Comment: That didn't work for me but `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();` did. Hopefully this will help someone.